# InvalidOperationException: No policy found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I am building a website in dotnet core and have recently started using claims based authentication and authorization.

In a view component I am checking if the user has access to a policy.

```
public NavigationViewComponent(
    IContextManager contextManager,
    IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
{
    _contextManager = contextManager;
    _authorizationService = authorizationService;
}

public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    var showAdmin = _contextManager.Principal != null &&
        (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(_contextManager.Principal, "Admin")).Succeeded;

    var vm = new NavigationViewModel
    {
        ShowAdmin = showAdmin
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

However, I am receiving the Exception `InvalidOperationException: No policy found: Admin.`.

My `startup.cs` contains the following inside the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasPermissionRequirement("ADMIN")));
});
```

What else do I need to configure in order to get this to work correctly?

For reference I am registering 3 additional `IAuthorizationHandler` implementations and 1 `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`.

**Edit**

For reference, the whole startup.cs looks something *similar* to this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        // Name and policy settings
        options.Cookie.Name         = "account";
        options.Cookie.SameSite     = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly     = true;

        // Sign the user out after 28 days of inactivity
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan    = TimeSpan.FromDays(28);

        // Challenge actions
        options.LoginPath          = new PathString("/account/login");
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Admin",
            policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasPermissionRequirement("ADMIN")));
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasPermissionHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, StrategyAuthorizationCrudHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserAuthorizationCrudHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, HasPermissionPolicyProvider>();

    // AddAntiforgery, AddSession,AddDistributedRedisCache and AddDataProtection omitted

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }

    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        CheckConsentNeeded    = httpContext => false,
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
        Secure                = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
    });

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-GB")
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures[0]),
        SupportedCultures     = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures   = supportedCultures
    });

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseMiddleware<UserMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**HasPermissionRequirement.cs**

```
public class HasPermissionRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Permission { get; private set; }

    public HasPermissionRequirement(string permission)
    {
        Permission = permission;
    }
}
```

**HasPermissionHandler.cs**

```
public class HasPermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasPermissionRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        HasPermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var hasPermission = context.User.HasClaim("Permission", requirement.Permission);
        if (hasPermission)
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**HasPermissionPolicyProvider.cs**

```
public class HasPermissionPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private const string PolicyPrefix = "HasPermission";

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (!policyName.StartsWith(PolicyPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy>(null);

        var permission = policyName.Substring(PolicyPrefix.Length);

        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
        policy.AddRequirements(new HasPermissionRequirement(permission));

        return Task.FromResult(policy.Build());
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync() => 
        Task.FromResult(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
}
```

Comment: Please notice that you are using *ASP.NET Core*. Whether it's on .NET Framework or .NET Core does not matter for this question. That said, we'll need to see the full startup class to see the order of the calls

Comment: I am unable to post the whole startup class due to sensitive information. Are there any particular `services.` or `app.` methods you'd like to see the order of?

Comment: No problem, just services. AddAuthentication/AddAuthorization/AddMvc (any configuration option of these too), and then app. UseAuthentication/UseMvc and related configuration

Comment: I have amended the post with the startup.cs content. It's baffling as I followed all of the documentation but can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: What happens if, just for testing, you put a `[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]` to the action?

Comment: When I apply that I get a similar but different exception: `InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Admin' was not found.`

Comment: Can you post the code for your has permission requirements and handlers please

Comment: Certainly, please see updated post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I decided to take a closer look at the `HasPermissionPolicyProvider` class. From the MS docs: `keep in mind that ASP.NET Core only uses one instance of IAuthorizationPolicyProvider` which doesn't behave like `IAuthorizationHandler`. Changed this class to look at static policies too and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by taking a closer look at the Microsoft documentation after being pointed in the right direction.

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider.md#multiple-authorization-policy-providers

> When using custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider implementations, keep in mind that ASP.NET Core only uses one instance of IAuthorizationPolicyProvider. If a custom provider isn't able to provide authorization policies for all policy names, it should fall back to a backup provider.

As a result I changed the implementation of my `HasPermissionPolicyProvider` to `CustomPolicyProvider` and the content is below:

```
public class CustomPolicyProvider : DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private const string PermissionPolicyPrefix = "HasPermission";

    public CustomPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        var policy = await base.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);

        if (policy != null) return policy;

        if (policyName.StartsWith(PermissionPolicyPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var permission = policyName.Substring(PermissionPolicyPrefix.Length);

            return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddRequirements(new HasPermissionRequirement(permission))
                .Build();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This means that you can only have one PolicyProvider which must handle all your logic. The change is to ensure that it calls the default implementation if you require multiple handler logic.